# How did it all started VS how did it all start?

Tags: meaning

I wanted to know if the first one is correct:

How did it all started?

Everybody mentioned to me that "How did it all start?" the correct form is but I always thought both ways are correct?

Comment: Only "How did it all start?" is correct.  When you make a question with *to do*, the other verb is used in its bare infinitive form and doesn't get conjugated.  This is one of the most common questions we get here, actually.